# Dynamic form names with redux-form

Tags: typescript, webpack, redux-form

I have a form component created using [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/).

I'm using the [`reduxForm()`](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/) HOC to connect the form component up to the [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/) redux store.

As part of that I have to provide a name for the form which acts as an ID under which [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/) stores the form data.

```
export const ContactAddEditForm = ReduxForm.reduxForm<FormData, Props>({
    form: "contactAddEdit"
})(ContactAddEdit);
```

In the example above I'm using the name "contactAddEdit".

I'd like to reuse this form in multiple places, all of which share the same data shape, but are backed by different data sources.

As a result that means that multiple versions of this same form could be on a page at one time, and so require different names so they're kept seperate in the store.

Due to that requirement, I need to be able to dynamically change the name being used to identify the form in the store.

e.g.

One instance might be called "personalContactAddEdit", and another might be called "businessContactAddEdit".

Or "contactOneAddEdit", "contactTwoAddEdit", and "contactThreeAddEdit".

etc.

I'm using modules written in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) with the ES Module syntax for exporting and importing. That's all bundled up with [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/).

I've been thinking about how to approach this problem and I've got a few ideas:

---

**Create a new specialized version of the class every time.**

This is probably the easiest, but least desirable option. I'd take the module code I have now, and wrap it in a function which takes the name as an argument, then return the result using the passed name. The problem with this is it'd have to run the full code of the module on every call.

---

**Have the bare component in a module without the HOC.**

Then create a new module for each unique name, importing the component and returning the result from the HOC.

e.g.

*PersonalContactAddEdit*

```
import * as ContactAddEdit from "./ContactAddEdit";

export const PersonalContactAddEditForm = ReduxForm.reduxForm<ContactAddEdit.FormData, ContactAddEdit.Props>({
    form: "personalContactAddEdit"
})(ContactAddEdit.ContactAddEdit);
```

*BusinessContactAddEdit*

```
import * as ContactAddEdit from "./ContactAddEdit";

export const BusinessContactAddEditForm = ReduxForm.reduxForm<ContactAddEdit.FormData, ContactAddEdit.Props>({
    form: "businessContactAddEdit"
})(ContactAddEdit.ContactAddEdit);
```

---

**Create a factory that, given a name, will either return an existing specialized version, or create a new one if it doesn't already exist.**

This is the flexibility of the first option, combined with the tidiness of the second.

---

I'm not sure of the best way to implement this pattern in this environment.

- Is there a standard/recommend approach for this requirement?
- Am I missing a better option than those listed above?
- If the factory is the best option, what would be the best way to implement it?

Since it's so closely coupled with the concept of modules it feels like something WebPack might support, but I haven't found any indications of that.

Let me know if I've missed any vital information, and I'll update the question.